# Extract time from a column in given

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook

The time column in my dataframe df looks like

```
Date_UTC
1998-05-02T00:00:00
1998-05-02T00:01:00
1998-05-02T00:02:00
1998-05-02T00:03:00
1998-05-02T00:04:00
1998-05-02T00:05:00
1998-05-02T00:06:00
1998-05-02T00:07:00
1998-05-02T00:08:00
1998-05-02T00:09:00
1998-05-02T00:10:00
```

I want to extract time values from it. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use:

````
df['time']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date_UTC']).dt.time

#if you want to only dates
df['Date_UTC']=pd.to_datetime(['Date_UTC']).dt.date```
````